# For $ x^3+y^2= 2x^2y+2 $ Find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ and the slope of the tangent to the curve at $(-1,-1)$

Tags: calculus

> For $ x^3+y^2= 2x^2y+2 $ Find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ and the slope of the tangent to the curve at $(-1,-1)$

Having a little problem finding the derivative in respect to $\frac{dy}{dx}$ for $2x^2y+2.$
To my understandings I need to use implicit differentiation; thus, wherever there is a $y$, after I take the derivative of $y$, I need to attach $\frac{dy}{dx}$. However, how does one do that for $2x^2y+2$?

Comment: Deriving $2x^2y$ you get $4xy+2x^2y'$

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}\frac{d}{dx}(2x^2y+2)&=2\frac{d}{dx}(x^2y)+\frac{d}{dx}(2)\\&=2\left(\left(\frac{d}{dx}(x^2)\right)\cdot y+(x^2)\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}\right)+0\\&=2\left(2xy+x^2\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}\right)\\&=4xy+2x^2\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}\end{align}$$

Comment: So are you factoring out the 2 and then utilizing the product rule. I follow the  pattern the "first term x the derivative of the second + the second term X the derivative of the 1st. I do not see that pattern when it comes to your answer. Can you explain your method please?

Comment: @Cetshwayo  mathlove is using the Product Rule in the form:  $(fg)' = f'g + fg'$.   It sounds like you learned it as $(fg)' = fg' + f'g$, which is equivalent.

Comment: Why is he allowed to factor the 2 out? Also, after factoring the 2 out I and doing a little algebra I got $ \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\frac{df}{dx}}{\frac{df}{dy}}=\frac{3x^2-4xy}{2y-2x^2}/ $

Answer (score 0):

let $$f(x,y)=x^3+y^2-2x^2y-2$$
$$\frac{df}{dx}=3x^2-4xy$$
$$\frac{df}{dy}=2y-2x^2$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\frac{df}{dx}}{\frac{df}{dy}}=\frac{3x^2-4xy}{2y-2x^2}$$

Comment: I got the same answer as you. How do you find the slope of the curve at (-1,-1)? Do I just plug -1 one where I see x and y then utilize the point slope form?